# Couldn't create folder in storage Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-filesystem

I'm trying to build an application which will only needs to work in the Chrome browser.
A part of this is that folders can be uploaded with dragdrop functionality.

The problem I am facing now is that I couldn't even create a temp folder to copy the dropped files/folders in.

Below is the code

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024 * 1024 * 500, function (bytes) {
        console.log('Allocated ' + bytes + ' bytes.');
        // request file system
        window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, bytes, function(fileSystem) {
            fs = fileSystem;
            cwd = fs.root;

            //log query usage and quota
            navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.queryUsageAndQuota(
            (used, total) => console.log(
                `using ${used} out of ${total}, or ${used/total*100}%`)
            );

            //create temp folder
            cwd.getDirectory('/temp', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(directory){
                multiplefilesDirectory = directory;

                console.log('directory',directory,multiplefilesDirectory);
            }, onError);

        });
    }, function (e) {
        console.log('Failed to allocate persistant storage!');
    });
```

There is no error  in requestQuota. it logs `Allocated 524288000 bytes.`
The queryUsageAndQuota logs `using 0 out of 0, or NaN%`, which seems like the storage size hasn't been changed.

Creation of the temp folder logs an error `Error: The operation failed because it would cause the application to exceed its storage quota.`. Probably because the unchanged storage size.

Did I make an mistake or is there another way to do this?

Comment: I believe the chrome storage does not have enough space for such things

Answer (score 0):

Check your freespace on filesystem.

In my case there was problem with free disc space. I asked for 1*1024*1024 and had 7 GB free from 1TB disc, that was 100% full using `df -h`.
Removed 28GB to have 97% full and started to work.